# If $\lim_{x\to a} |g(x)| =\lim_{x\to a} |\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}| = \infty$, is it true that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) + g(x) = \lim_{x\to a} f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, asymptotics

Let $\lim_{x\to a} |g(x)| =\lim_{x\to a} |\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}| = \infty$ for some $a\in \mathbb R$. I would like to show that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) + g(x) = \lim_{x\to a} f(x)$. Below is my attempt.

Without losing generality, let us assume that $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \infty$. It can be seen that $\infty = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} + 1 = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)+g(x)}{g(x)}$. Therefore, $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) + g(x) = (\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)+g(x)}{g(x)}) (\lim_{x\to a} g(x)) = (\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)})(\lim_{x\to a} g(x)) = \lim_{x\to a} f(x).$

Whereas the last line follows from the ["product of limits equal limit of product" rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362216/limit-of-a-product-is-the-product-of-the-limits-when) for the $\pm$infinity/$\pm$infinity cases.

Is the proof good enough to demonstrated the result? If not, is this true in the first place? It would be appreciated to receive some help from you.

Comment: I'm more concerned with the case in which both $f$ and $g$ have infinite limits but different signs.

Comment: $f(x)+g(x)\to f(x)$ is not a well-defined mathematical statement. (You also haven't explicitly defined what you mean by $\ll$.) It sounds like you're trying to prove something like: if $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=-\infty$, then $\lim_{x\to a} \big( f(x)+g(x) \big)=\infty$ as well; is that accurate?

Comment: @GregMartin: That is accurate.

Comment: In that case, I recommend first proving that $f(x)+g(x) > \frac{f(x)}2$ when $x$ is near $a$, and then use a comparison test. More generally, trying to apply limit laws that work for finite limits is not a rigorous or reliable way to prove limit laws for infinite limits; it's usually better to go back to the definitions of infinite limits and prove what you want directly.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Rigorous proof is always better. But I couldn't derive a proper one. Besides, isn't for the case of the product law we get the immediate result? Since $\infty \times \infty$ is not an indeterminate form.  I would also like to know if my proof contains any err in it.

Comment: What if $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x)$ does not exists? Take $a=0,g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: I see, thank you very much for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is true. As Greg Martin says, it's only reliable to prove it from the definitions. Throughout the proof I'll only write one $\delta >0$, because we can take the minimum of all $\delta_i$'s and call it $\delta$. \

Let $M>1$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}|>\sqrt{M}$  and $|g(x)|>\sqrt{M}$ whenever $0<|x-a|<\delta$, this implies $|f(x)|>\sqrt{M}|g(x)|>M$ whenever $0<|x-a|<\delta$ (note that same is true for any $M>0$). So $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}|f(x)|=\infty$. To prove it we must assume the existence of $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)$. Now we can have the following cases:\

(i)     Let $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}g(x)=-\infty$. Choose $M_1>0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $f(x)>M_1>0$ and $g(x)< -\frac{M_1}{\sqrt{M}-1}<0$ whenever $0<|x-a|<\delta$. Then for $0<|x-a|<\delta$ , $|f(x)|=f(x)$ and $|g(x)|=-g(x)$. Let $0<|x-a|<\delta$ then:

\begin{align}
&|f(x)|>\sqrt{M}|g(x)|=(\sqrt{M}-1)|g(x)|+|g(x)| \\
&\Rightarrow f(x)-|g(x)| > (\sqrt{M}-1)|g(x)|\\ 
&\Rightarrow f(x)+g(x)> (\sqrt{M}-1)(-g(x))>M_1
\end{align}
Thus $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} (f(x)+g(x))=\infty=\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)$. \

(ii)     Let $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}g(x)=\infty$. Choose $M_1>0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $f(x)<-\frac{M_1}{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{M}}}<0$ and $g(x)> M_1>0$ whenever $0<|x-a|<\delta$. Then for $0<|x-a|<\delta$ , $|f(x)|=-f(x)$ and $|g(x)|=g(x)$. Let $0<|x-a|<\delta$ then:

\begin{align}
&|f(x)|>\sqrt{M}|g(x)| \\
&\Rightarrow -f(x)>\sqrt{M}g(x)\\
&\Rightarrow -\frac{1}{\sqrt{M}}f(x)>g(x)\\
&\Rightarrow (1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{M}})f(x)-f(x)>g(x)\\
&\Rightarrow f(x)+g(x) < (1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{M}})f(x)<-M_1
\end{align}
Thus $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} (f(x)+g(x))=-\infty=\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)$.\

(iii)      Let $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}g(x)=-\infty$. Choose $M_1>0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $f(x)<-\frac{M_1}{2}$ and $g(x)<- \frac{M_1}{2}$ whenever $0<|x-a|<\delta$. Then for, $0<|x-a|<\delta$, $f(x)+g(x)<-M_1$
Thus $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} (f(x)+g(x))=-\infty=\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)$.\

(iv)   The case $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}g(x)=\infty$ can be done in the same way as (iii).

(v)   Let $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)=\infty$, $\lim_{x \rightarrow a-}g(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow a+}g(x)=\infty$ (the opposite  limits of $g$ will be similar). Then from (i) considering the neighborhood $(a-\delta, a)$ we get $\lim_{x \rightarrow a-} (f(x)+g(x))=\infty=\lim_{x \rightarrow a-}f(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)$. Then from (iv) considering the neighborhood $(a,a+\delta)$ we get
$\lim_{x \rightarrow a+} (f(x)+g(x))=\infty=\lim_{x \rightarrow a+}f(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)$. Combining those we have $\lim_{x \rightarrow a-} (f(x)+g(x))=\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow a+} (f(x)+g(x))$ which implies
$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} (f(x)+g(x))=\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)$.

(vi) The case when $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)=-\infty$, $\lim_{x \rightarrow a-}g(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow a+}g(x)=\infty$ (the opposite  limits of $g$ will be similar) is done similayly.