# What is $\lim \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{n} \mathrm{d}m$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have this probably silly doubt about what is $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \dfrac{1}{n} \mathrm{d}m$.

Here I have the Lebesgue integral.

If I'm calculating correctly, each integral in the sequence is $\infty$, so I have a constant sequence of $\infty$, and a constant sequence converges to any of its elements. (?) (This may fail for infinity, but I don't know how to verify.)

Looking at other way, I can take $\dfrac{1}{n}$ out of the integral, and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}1\mathrm{d}m=\infty$, but $\lim \frac{1}{n} = 0$, so I have $0.\infty$, which in measure theory is $0$.

I'm really confused, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The value of the integral is $\infty$ for all $n$.

Comment: So the limit is also $\infty$? My problem is I don't know what is the limit of a "constant" sequence of infinity

Comment: The Integral is $\infty$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Then taking the limit $n \to \infty$ doesn't change anything because the value is independent of $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you take the $\frac1n$ out of the integral, you have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\Bbb R^n}\frac1ndm
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1n\int_{\Bbb R^n}dm\right)
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac\infty n
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\infty
=\infty.
$$

Rewriting $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1n\int_{\Bbb R^n}dm\right)$ as $(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n)(\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\Bbb R^n}dm)$ is only valid if the resulting product (in this case $0\times\infty$) is not indeterminate. See: [when is the limit of a product the product of the limits?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1362216/279914)

Answer (score 0):

In measure theory, there are some important theorems that justify interchange $\lim \int = \int \lim$.  But the hypotheses of those theorems are important, too.  Your example does not satisfy the needed hypotheses.