# Differentiating $\sin x$ using limits

Tags: limits

Below i am trying to differentiate $\sin x$ using first principle.

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin(x+h)-\sin x}{h}$$
$$=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin x(\cos h-1)}
{h}+\cos x\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin h}{h}$$

This is a bit uncoventional from the way it is usually done in textbooks using the
$\sin C-\sin D$ formula. My concern is the first term in the third line,which is

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin x(\cos h-1)}{h}=-\sin x \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{2\sin^2{\frac{h}{2}}}{h}$$

When evaluating this limit,is it okay to split the limit $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{2\sin^2{\frac{h}{2}}}{\frac{h^2}{2}} \times \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h}{2}=2\times 0=0$$
as shown?

In other words,is it always okay to split limits as $$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) \times g(x)=\lim_{x \to a} f(x) \times \lim_{x \to a} g(x)=L_{f(x)}\times L_{g(x)}$$

as long as both $L_{f(x)}$ and $L_{g(x)}$ don't turn out to be undefined *EVEN if both or either of $L_{f(x)}, L_{g(x)}$ are/is $0$*? Please enlighten me.

Comment: Yes, it's fine to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is correct to split the limit of the product into a product of limits, as long as both limits are well-defined and as long as you are not in the case $0\times\pm\infty$. All other cases (finite$\times$finite, $\pm\infty\times\pm\infty$, non-zero$\times\pm\infty$) are fine.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362216/limit-of-a-product-is-the-product-of-the-limits-when) for a previous answer on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an alternative way is by using differentials.

From trigonometry:
$$\sin(x + dx)= \sin(x)\cos(dx) + \cos(x)\sin(dx)$$

Since $\cos(dx)\approxeq 1$ and $\sin(dx)\approxeq dx$, we have:

$$\sin(x + dx)= \sin(x) + \cos(x)dx$$

But we know that the derivative of a function is the linear term in the infinitesimal $dx$ when expressing the function with Taylor series.

So $f^\prime(x)= \cos(x)$

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.  Moreover, your analysis is not rigorous.